# Consultar valores nulos en firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Básicamente lo que busco es hacer un `where` y consultar un valor nullo.

Estoy utilizando la libreria de https://github.com/angular/angularfire

según la documentación https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

puedo hacer esto

```
afs.collection('items', ref => ref.where('size', '==', size) ).valueChanges()
```

pero me gustaría hacer algo como:

```
afs.collection('items', ref => ref.where('size', '==', null) ).valueChanges()
```

pero no lo consigo!

Comment: Podrías hacer uso de ese filtro si tienes creada la variable size y asignada a null dentro de cada item.

Answer (score 0):

:D En primer lugar decirte que esto no es posible si este campo no existe en los documentos  de firebase, para que esto funciones debes crear dicho campo en los documentos de firebase y asignarle el valor null especificamente.
Este enlace creo que te puede ayudar.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806860/how-to-query-cloud-firestore-for-non-existing-keys-of-documents